# Visual Studio Java Syntax Highlight

Tags: java, visual-studio, syntax, highlight

Okay so I've spent more time than I should have researching on this topic. I'm using latest (so far) Visual Studio Community 2019, and in my project I need to maintain few Java files.

When I open Java files, there is no syntax coloring. I've tried installing some extensions, even tried building my own extension with `Textmate Grammar Template` extension, tried editing `%userprofile%\.vs\Extensions\java\syntax\Java.plist` (even tried copying some other versions and renaming it to .tmLanguage), I don't even remember what other combinations I tried but none of them work. And pretty much every single thing I tried works for other new languages I tried adding just to test if such method does actually do something, and they do.

When I do a right click on .java file and hit "Open With", then when I choose "Common Language Editor Supporting Textmate Bundles (Default)" (which is obviously the default one), it says "The file cannot be opened with the selected editor. Please, choose another Editor."

The use case I have is a bit weird but I do need those Java files inside Visual Studio. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to edit those files without any syntax highlight support?

Comment: I think Java within Visual Studio isn't a thing at all. I can't find a single component that is related to Java.

Comment: I don't think there is any extension for Java to speak of for VS2019. There are two LSP servers for Java, but the LSP client in VS2019 is far behind the current version 3.16. I've had to jump through hoops interfacing my own server. You can probably get a TM markup working but TM is terrible. It only displays lexer tokens, not CFG markup, let alone static semantics, builds, etc. What I recommend is Open in VSCode extension by Mads.

Comment: All I need is to keep source files and edit them occasionally, like any syntax highlighting would be cool. I dont need any Java tools and I know its not a thing, like even the basic highlighting and nothing else would help. I'm just not sure why TM is working for other languages fine, but isn't working for Java at all. Even that would help in my case.